# tsconfig target set to es5 but still uses let & const

Tags: javascript, typescript, uglifyjs

I am trying to use UglifyJS on code generated by tsc.

The target is set to `es5` but the generated code still uses let & const declarations (no idea why because they are not in the ES5 spec) hence uglifyjs keep crying about it.

Does anyone know how can I make tsc use var instead of let & const? (Targeting `es3` is not an option)

Here is the current tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "pretty": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": [
      "webpack",
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".tmp",
    "lib",
    "e2e/**"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./custom.d.ts",
    "./demo/playground/hmr-playground.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.ts?",
    "demo/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you target es5 Typescript should eliminate `const` and `let` are you sure that Typescript is picking up the `tsconfig` you are editing?

Comment: Yes, or at least it seems that is the correct one. https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc this is the project I am trying to build. (Npm run bundle) target is set to es5 in tsconfig.

Comment: Can you confirm:  stick a bunch of garbage in your tsconfig and do a build.  Does it break the build, or build as though nothing had changed?

Comment: It does break it,
`import * as ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin';
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`
i get this strange message, if I type any kind of jibberish in tsconfig

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir ReDoc author here. The issue is in the dependencies. They may ship es6 code. They are not getting transpired by typescript and are just bundled in with webpack as is.

I even have exclusions in my webpack config for such deps: https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/blob/master/webpack.config.ts#L118

Comment: It is very strange because if I run `npm run bundle`, the bundles contain es6 features although your bundles, distributed on CDN, don't. Do you do any subsequent transformations after `bundle` ?

Comment: @AndreiSorescu most likely you installed some your dependencies which ship es6 code and you do not transpile it.

Comment: Even if I build from `redoc/master` I still get a es5+ code in `redoc.standalone.js`. It's not the dependencies. It has something to do with the environment not sure what tho. I have tried on multiple computer and I get the same result.

Comment: Later edit: This happens on an Windows machine, if I am building inside docker from the same source files it works just fine...

Answer (score 0):

your config says "target": "es6",